# Kivy Double Tap

Tags: python, touch, kivy, double-click, motionevent

I have a lot of questions...)

I'm trying to get Kivy to register a double tap as the motion event used to add/remove a widget [ since there is no 'hide this widget option'... maybe in the next update] because a single touch down makes the widget appear and disappear and appear and disappear over and over again (which is annoying).

My code (the important bits) [Python, followed by Kivy]:

```
class SomeScreen(Screen):
    def on_touch_down(touch, *args): 
        if touch.is_double_tap:
            try: self.add_widget(*args)
            except: self.remove_widget(*args)
    pass
```

Kivy:

```
FloatLayout:
    on_touch_down:
        on_touch_down(nameofwidget)
```

It is giving a 'KeyError: "is_double_tap"'.

I have also tried this collection of solutions.

```
is_double_tap: 
    self.on_touch_down

>>> KeyError: "is_double_tap"
```

Another solution -

```
on_touch_down: 
    self.touch.is_double_tap = try: self.add_widget(nameofwidget), except: self.remove_widget(nameofwidget)

>>> invalid syntax [ at try:]
```

Another solution:

```
on_touch_down: 
 self.on_touch_down.is_double_tap: try [ same as above]
>>> invalid syntax [ at try:]
```

I think it is important to include that

```
on_touch_down: 
    try: self.add_widget(nameofwidget)
    except: self.remove_widget(nameofwidget)
```

with no definition of the on_touch_down function on the Python side, works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeScreen(Screen):
    def on_touch_down(touch, *args):
```

This is a method, your problem is you're missing the implicit `self`. Declare it instead as `def on_touch_down(self, touch):`.

```
FloatLayout:
    on_touch_down:
        on_touch_down(nameofwidget)
```

I don't think this will work (just crash), because `on_touch_down` is not a defined variable.